# Microsoft Graph API Logic App Authentication

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, azure-authentication

I am having a difficult time getting a Microsoft Graph API call to work.  Specifically, I am having a hard time with the authentication process working.  I followed the directions in this article

http://martink.me/articles/using-microsoft-graph-in-logic-apps

However, when I make the api call of [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/%7Bid%7D), I get the error:

> Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user.  Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints.  Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps.

I then added an oAuth token call to get a token.  Then I used that token in the Authorization header when making the Microsoft Graph Api call.  I still get the same error.

Can anyone provide guidance on how best to make an Graph Api call in LogicApps? Do I only need the authentication discussed in the article?  Or, do I need to call the Graph Api with an Authorization token?  Do I need to make an oAuth authorization call before I make the oAuth token call?

Comment: How did you request the token? What authentication flow is used?

Comment: I use this url to request the token
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token.  I am using the client_credentials flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is caused by the token acquired using the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). In this flow, there is no context for **/Me**.

This type of grant is commonly used for server-to-server interactions that must run in the background, without immediate interaction with a user(no user logged in).

For your problem, you are using client credential flow and you are granting application permissions, so you should request **/users**.

```
 GET   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}
```

[image]